# Updating MySQL value is not saved PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following database-model:
[image]

This database gets filled by loading in a CSV file. Let's say this is the CSV file:
[image]

This is how the CSV gets loaded into the database:
First I take all the values of `foo_name` and insert them into the table `Foo`. I only fill name. ID is autoincrement. The same happens for `bar_name`. Note that all `names` can only exist one time in the table. So even when `Jefferson` appears twice in the CSV, it exists only one time in the actual database table. Same for `Foo`.**strong text**

That works perfectly. The tables get filled. But as you can see, the table `Foo` holds a foreign key to `Bar`.

I want to put `Bar(ID)` into `Foo(bar_id)` where `Foo(name)` and `Bar(name)` are in the same row in the CSV file.

I tried to do it by looping over the CSV file again. For every `Foo(name)` I retrieve `Foo(ID)`. I also retrieve `Bar(ID)`. Then I update `Foo(bar_id)` with the `ID` in `Bar` that matches `Bar(name)`.

This is the code in my while-loop for reading the csv:

```
$foo = $column[0];
            $bar = $column[1];

            $foo_id = 0;
            $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT ID from Foo WHERE name=?");
            $stmt->bind_param("s", $name_);
            $name_ = $foo;
            $stmt->execute();
            $stmt->bind_result($id);
            $stmt->fetch();
            $foo_id = $id;
            $stmt->close();

            $bar_id = 0;
            $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT ID from bars WHERE name=?");
            $stmt->bind_param("s", $name_);
            $name_ = $bar;
            $stmt->execute();
            $stmt->bind_result($id);
            $stmt->fetch();
            $bar_id = $id;
            $stmt->close();

            //echo $foo_id . " - " . $bar_id . "<br>";

            $stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE foo SET bar_id=? WHERE ID=?");
            if (!$stmt) {
                die("Statement failed (" . $stmt->errno . "): " . $conn->error);
            }
            $stmt->bind_param("ii", $bar_, $id_);
            $bar_ = $bar_id;
            $id_ = $foo_id;
            if(!$stmt->execute()) {
                echo $stmt->error;
            }
            echo $stmt->affected_rows . "<br>";
            $stmt->close();
```

This line `echo $foo_id . " - " . $bar_id . "<br>";` nicely outputs `foo_id` and `bar_id` like it should. `$stmt->affected_rows` does return `1` almost each time. So something should be updated. I got no errors at all. And doing `UPDATE foo SET bar_id=? WHERE ID=?` manually in the database works.

Despite this all, the column `bar_id` is not updated/saved.

Comment: Try to comment `$stmt->close();`

Comment: you have far too  many variables butwhat is  $definition_id suppoed tio be should it not be $foo_id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code above is working. I made some other stupid mistake.
While reading the CSV-file for the first time to fill the tables, the values first get written to an array.

Then I read it another time to set the relations.

The problem is that I wrote from memory to database at the very end of my code. Resulting in overwriting the column-values holding the relation. Solved.